# Python PIL/Pillow - Pad image to desired size (eg. A4)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a JPG/PNG/PDF image, and I'd like to get it on a A4 page, centered, as PDF (FYI: so that it's easy for my end-users to display/print it).

In either order:

- pad the image to fill an A4 (with white)
- transform to PDF

I can do `im.save('filename.pdf', 'PDF', resolution=100.0)` to save an `Image` object to PDF, but I don't know how to do the other task.

I'd really prefer using Pillow, but other answers are welcome.

Comment: I think you need to get the DPI, then calculate desired resolution for that size using the DPI

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(my_image_file)
a4im = Image.new('RGB',
                 (595, 842),   # A4 at 72dpi
                 (255, 255, 255))  # White
a4im.paste(im, im.getbbox())  # Not centered, top-left corner
a4im.save(outputfile, 'PDF', quality=100)
```

This is taking as hypothesis that `my_image_file` has the same resolution, 72dpi.

Comment: What happens when `my_image_file` is a different resolution? Do I need to transform `im`?

Comment: You can get DPI of the picture with `x_dpi, y_dpi = im.info['dpi']`, and use it to compute the expected size of the new picture, basically: `int(<size in mm> * <dpi> / 25.4)`.

Comment: ... note that sometimes the header with DPI information is not stored with the picture.